# Assign to NEW by key in a Postgres trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions, plpgsql

In the trigger body, how can I assign a value to `NEW` by it's field name?
That's what I want to do:

```
some_key = "some_column";
NEW[some_key] = 5;
```

Comment: I know that, thats why I raised this question. There is a hacky way to access variable from NEW dynamically like this 
**EXECUTE 'SELECT ($1).'||column_name||' ;' INTO  some_var USING NEW;** but I cant assign to **NEW** like that. @dezso

Comment: And @dezso , whenever someone calls map an array - my heart bleeds

Comment: Yes, but can you access in postgres array by key? Im just saying that some scripts don't show difference between array and map, and I know people that programm such scripts and don't know the difference between those two.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @dezso, I guess you just can't achieve this in postgres.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, there *is* no "trigger body" (unlike Oracle). In Postgres you have a [trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) (also, misleadingly, called "procedure") with a function body and 0-n triggers (without body) calling this function.

The special variable `NEW` in plpgsql trigger functions is neither a map nor an array; [it's a **record** holding the new row:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

> `NEW`
>
> Data type `RECORD`; variable holding the new database row for
> `INSERT`/`UPDATE` operations in row-level triggers. This variable is
> unassigned in statement-level triggers and for `DELETE` operations.

Assigning to a field (or column) of `NEW` is simple. The documented [assignment operator is `:=`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7462322/939860). ([Since Postgres 9.4 also `=`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22001209/939860))

```
NEW.some_key := 5;
```

What you seem to be looking for is to **parameterize the column name**, which isn't quite as simple.
The [additional module `hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html#HSTORE-OP-TABLE) provides the [**`#=`** operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html#HSTORE-OP-TABLE). (It's included in pretty much all standard distributions.) Install the module *once* per database with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
```

Then you can:

```
NEW := NEW #= '"some_key"=>"5"'::hstore;
```

Sets the column `some_key` to '5' - if the column exists.

- An explicit cast to `hstore` is optional. The operator `#=` coerces a string literal to the right data type automatically.
- `hstore` only stores text strings, so a given literal for the value may have to be cast *twice* - a very minor drawback compared to alternative solutions.
- The given string literal has to fit the **data type** of the column, or an exception is raised.
- If no column with the given name exists, nothing is changed, no exception raised.

Related answer with **details and an alternative solution**:

- [How to set value of composite variable field using dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7782641/939860)

#### Code example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_tbl_ins_bef()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW := NEW #= '"some_key"=>"5"';
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER ins_bef
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_tbl_ins_bef();
```

Postgres 11 or later allows to replace the misleding term `PROCEDURE` (the old syntax will keep working for the foreseeable future):

```
...
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION trg_tbl_ins_bef();
```

Comment: I haven't thought about `hstore`, it's much simpler than my approach.

Comment: Check out the linked answer. Pavel and I worked hard on a solution before the `#=` operator was introduced - and found one, too.

Comment: I didn't said NEW is a map or array, writing this **NEW[some_key] = 5;** I was just giving a hint what I want to achieve. The thing with hstore is genius, would never think of it by myself.

Answer (score 3):

I must admit that this is no easy way of solving it, but at least it's a way.  I created the below example as a standalone one, to avoid all clutter with trigger creation and such.  If you use it in a trigger, you can remove the declaration and initialization of `p` and replace the remaining use with `NEW`.

```
DO $$
DECLARE p members_test; 
BEGIN
    p := (1,2,3);
    CREATE TEMP TABLE t ON COMMIT DROP AS SELECT p.*; -- a one row table holding 
                                                      -- the values of the variable

    EXECUTE format($e$UPDATE t SET %s = 43$e$, 'b'); -- this way you can access 
                                                     -- the columns dynamically

    SELECT * INTO p FROM t; -- assign the new values back to the variable
    RAISE INFO 'p: %', p;
END;
$$;

INFO:  p: (1,43,3)
```