# Use variable as column name

Tags: postgresql, trigger, dynamic-sql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create trigger in PostgreSQL 14:

```
 create or replace function add_stats_to_player() returns trigger as $add_stats_to_player$
    declare
        equipment_id int := new.player_equipment_armor['armor_id'];
        equipment_stats varchar[] := array(select jsonb_object_keys(armor_stats['stats']) from equipments_armor where armor_id = equipment_id);
        equipment_stat varchar;

    begin
        raise notice '%', equipment_id;
        foreach equipment_stat in array equipment_stats loop
                if old.player_equipment_armor['stats'][equipment_stat] is not null then
                     update players set equipment_stat = equipment_stat - old.player_equipment_armor['stats'][equipment_stat] + new.player_equipment_armor['stats'][equipment_stat] where player_id = new.player_id;
                end if;
        end loop;
        return new;
    END;
$add_stats_to_player$ language plpgsql;

create trigger add_stats_to_player after insert or update of player_equipment_armor on players
    for each row WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() < 1) execute function add_stats_to_player();
```

Can I make a column name from the variable `equipment_stat`, or is that a bad idea?

**update**
Here's how I did it

```
create or replace function add_stats_to_player() returns trigger as $add_stats_to_player$
    declare
        equipment_id int := new.player_equipment_armor['armor_id'];
        equipment_stats varchar[] := array(select jsonb_object_keys(armor_stats['stats']) from equipments_armor where armor_id = equipment_id);
        equipment_stat varchar;
    begin
        if (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') then
            foreach equipment_stat in array equipment_stats loop
                    if old.player_equipment_armor['stats'][equipment_stat] is not null then
                       execute 'update players set ' || equipment_stat || ' = ' || equipment_stat || ' - ' || old.player_equipment_armor['stats'][equipment_stat] || '+' || new.player_equipment_armor['stats'][equipment_stat] || ' where player_id = ' || new.player_id;
                    else
                       execute 'update players set ' || equipment_stat || ' = ' || new.player_equipment_armor['stats'][equipment_stat] || ' where player_id = ' || new.player_id;
                    end if;
            end loop;
        elseif  (TG_OP = 'INSERT') then
            foreach equipment_stat in array equipment_stats loop
                execute 'update players set ' || equipment_stat || ' = ' || new.player_equipment_armor['stats'][equipment_stat] || ' where player_id = ' || new.player_id;
            end loop;
        end if;
        return new;
    end;
$add_stats_to_player$ language plpgsql;

create trigger add_stats_to_player after insert or update of player_equipment_armor on players
    for each row WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() < 1) execute procedure add_stats_to_player();
```

Comment: Please provide a *complete* function definition, not just the rump that is invalid without the header. And always your version of Postgres. Also show the trigger definition. And clarify your question, please. *"Can I make a column name from the 'equipment_stat' variable"*  ... do you want to use the value of `equipment_stat` as column name in the `UPDATE` command? There may be a simple pure SQL solution for this. Better yet, you should probably work with a normalized table design.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter,Yes I want to use the value of the `equipment_stat ` variable, and I couldn't find a way to do that.
If you can do it I would be very grateful.

Comment: You would need dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`. But I am hesitant to even show a solution because your approach is backwards in multiple ways. You shouldn't `UPDATE` the same row repeatedly. Much less the triggering row itself. And it makes no sense to `RETURN NEW;` in an `AFTER` trigger. You probably should use a `BEFORE` trigger and just assign new values to each `NEW.column`. Your `IF` condition also looks suspicious. Guess that's there to shoe in both `INSERT` and `UPDATE` case into the same trigger. Start by splitting both cases to separate triggers ...

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/144395/3684 or https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/105928/3684

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, Thanks for the explanation and guidance.

Comment: Does this have to be an `AFTER` trigger for a reason? `BEFORE` would be *much* simpler and cheaper.

Comment: Probably yes, but I was getting various errors, so now I just want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't let you do this. :)

Don't repeatedly `UPDATE` the triggering row. That's **hugely** inefficient and error-prone.

Use a **`BEFORE`** trigger instead, where you can simply assign new values to columns of the triggering row before writing it to the table.

Only covering the **`INSERT`** case. Extend to `UPDATE` accordingly.

#### Simplistic function with loop

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ins_bef_player()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   equipment_stat text;
BEGIN
   FOR equipment_stat IN
      SELECT jsonb_object_keys(armor_stats['stats'])
      FROM   equipments_armor
      WHERE  armor_id = (NEW.player_equipment_armor->>'armor_id')::int
   LOOP
      NEW := jsonb_populate_record(NEW, jsonb_build_object(equipment_stat, NEW.player_equipment_armor->'stats'->>equipment_stat));
   END LOOP;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER add_stats_to_player
BEFORE INSERT ON players
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION ins_bef_player();
```

Much better than expensive multiple `UPDATE`s. But still inefficient. You don't need the loop with multiple assignment at all.

#### Much smarter [`jsonb_populate_record()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE)

At best, one straight invocation of `jsonb_populate_record()` is all you need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ins_bef_player()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW := jsonb_populate_record(NEW, NEW.player_equipment_armor['stats']);  -- that's all !
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;
```

See:

- [Use trigger to synchronize columns with fields in json column on insert or update](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105721/use-trigger-to-synchronize-columns-with-fields-in-json-column-on-insert-or-updat/105928#105928)

Additional keys in `player_equipment_armor['stats']` that have no matching field in `NEW` are discarded automatically. And additional fields in `NEW` that have no mo match in `player_equipment_armor['stats']` are kept as is.

If `armor_stats['stats']` needs to be applied to remove keys, you can do that, too:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ins_bef_player()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW := jsonb_populate_record(NEW
          , NEW.player_equipment_armor['stats']
          - ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_object_keys(NEW.player_equipment_armor['stats'])
                  EXCEPT ALL
                  SELECT jsonb_object_keys(armor_stats['stats'])
                  FROM   equipments_armor e
                  WHERE  e.armor_id = (NEW.player_equipment_armor->>'armor_id')::int)
          );
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=afca2edb0f26167d1f01b2ef967f74fd)*

This removes all keys that are not present `armor_stats['stats']` before calling `jsonb_populate_record()`. See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)