# Dynamic trigger function to delete oldest rows of a table

Tags: postgresql, trigger, format

I am trying to generalize a trigger that deletes the oldest rows in a table as new rows are added. Since the number of rows to retain depends on the table, I am passing that number to the trigger function as an argument. When I use `format()` to interpolate the table name, it appears I am losing access to `new`, as described in [Trigger function taking column names as parameters to modify the row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127787/trigger-function-taking-column-names-as-parameters-to-modify-the-row).

Do I require `hstore` to accomplish this, or is there a simpler approach?

Current code:

```sql
create or replace function drop_over_n()
    returns trigger
    language plpgsql as $$
        begin
            execute format('
                with chrono_by_usr as (
                    select id, row_number()
                    over (partition by usr_id order by created_at) as row_number
                    from %I
                    where usr_id = new.usr_id and id != new.id
                )
                delete from %I
                where id in (
                    select id
                    from chrono_by_usr
                    where row_number > %s
                );
            ', tg_table_name, tg_table_name, tg_argv[0]);
            return null;
        end;
    $$;

create or replace trigger limit_recent_finding
    after insert on recent_finding
    for each row execute function drop_over_n(50);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you wrote that, `new` is interpreted as part of the SQL statement, but the SQL engine has no idea about the variables in your PL/pgSQL code. You will have to use a parameter:

```
EXECUTE format('... where usr_id = $1.usr_id') USING NEW;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! Now that it works, it looks like there are some other flaws in my code, but this definitely answers the question.