# Create hstore from key-value result set

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, hstore

I have following columns:

```
key | value
-----------
foo | 1
bar | 2
```

Is there a recommended way to turn this into `hstore`?

```
{foo => 1, bar => 2}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [the function **`hstore()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE).

There are several overlaoded versions of that functions. One takes a single text array with keys *and* values. Another one takes two text arrays, one with keys, the other one with values. Either works for you. Demo:

```
SELECT hstore(array_agg(ARRAY[key, value::text]))     AS option1
     , hstore(array_agg(key), array_agg(value::text)) AS option2
FROM  (VALUES ('foo', 1), ('bar', 2)) AS t(key, value);
```

`option1` requires Postgres 9.5 or later, where [`array_agg()` for multidimensional arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) was introduced. For older versions see:

- [Is there something like a zip() function in PostgreSQL that combines two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414750/is-there-something-like-a-zip-function-in-postgresql-that-combines-two-arrays/12414884#12414884)

If `value` is not type `text`, you may need the cast I added: `value::text`

The additional module hstore has to be installed in the database, of course.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;
```

Related:

- [Assignment of a column with dynamic column name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144388/assignment-of-a-column-with-dynamic-column-name/144395#144395)
- [Is it recommended to install extensions into pg_catalog schema?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107389/is-it-recommended-to-install-extensions-into-pg-catalog-schema/107418#107418)